# CMU sphinx livespeech example

Tags: java, speech-recognition, zk, cmusphinx

my goal is to let users speak by clicking a button and then when they click the button for stopping, the console outputs the result.
I tried to apply the code that the CMU sphinx official website writes, as the following code:

```
LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
// Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.
recognizer.startRecognition(true);
SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
// Pause recognition process. It can be resumed then with startRecognition(false).
recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

This is how I implemented with zk-maven project:

```
public class SphinxSpeechRecog extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private SpeechResult result;

    public SphinxSpeechRecog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Listen("onClick=#speakbtn")
    public void startSpeaking() throws IOException, InstantiationException {
        //System.out.println("hi");
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
        recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        result = recognizer.getResult();
        recognizer.stopRecognition();

    }
    @Listen("onClick=#stopspeakbtn")
    public void stopSpeaking() {

        System.out.print("result: "+result);
    }

}
```

the frontend(.zul file):

```
<?page title="sphinx speech recognition" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window title="sphinx speech recognition" border="normal" apply="sphinx.SphinxSpeechRecog">
        <button id="speakbtn" label="speak"/>
        <button id="stopspeakbtn" label="stop speaking"/> 
    </window>
</zk>
```

The java(eclipse) console outputs some weird result like this **(after so many minutes)**:

> result: edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult@3be41473

What can I do to optimize my code? And how to get the spoken words I really want to see?

Comment: I've found that result.getWords() will return some words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(WordResult word : result.getWords()) {
    System.out.print(word.toString());          
}
```

See more examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult).